# Get data from angularJs to java

Tags: java, angularjs

How can I get data from angularjs to java and show data in my html

for example I want search date from 2016/12/21 to 2015/12/21

how can I send it to java

function used is DateVisit

### angularJs code

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('projectsEvaluationApp')
        .factory('Visit', Visit)
        .factory('DateVisit',DateVisit);

    Visit.$inject = ['$resource'];
    DateVisit.$inject = ['$resource'];

    function DateVisit ($resource) {
        var service = $resource('api/visits/:id', {}, {
            'get': {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true
            },
            'query': {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true,
                params: {fromDate: null, toDate: null}
            }
        });

        return service;

    function Visit ($resource) {
        var resourceUrl =  'api/visits/:id';

        return $resource(resourceUrl, {}, {
            'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
            'get': {
                method: 'GET',
                transformResponse: function (data) {
                    if (data) {
                        data = angular.fromJson(data);
                    }
                    return data;
                }
            },
            'update': { method:'PUT' }
        });
    }
})();
```

### Java code :

```
@GetMapping("/visits")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<List<Visit>> getAllVisits(Pageable pageable)
    throws URISyntaxException {
    log.debug("REST request to get a page of Visits");
    Page<Visit> page = visitService.findAll(pageable);
    HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(page, "/api/visits");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(page.getContent(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Have you heard of making a REST call?  Sending data via Angular isn't too different than with any other UI framework.

Comment: `getAllVisits` cannot search dates. Seems like you use JHipster, so I would recommend you to enable `ElasticSearch`.